# click a button in a grid row to popup with color highlight row (webgrid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I dont know jquery very well but I am just trying my best. Need your help and hope you will.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4. When you click the button (btnDetails) to popup, the specific PersonId (101) row should be highlighted (yellow). It is working but when you click the next button with another PersonId (102) row, the previous PersonId(101) highlight still remains. Thats my problem. I want the PersonId (101) highlight row to be gone when you click the next button with another PersonId(102) to get highlight row. How to do this? Hope you understand my english. Please look at my below code. Hope you can fix it for me. Thanks!

```
    @grid.GetWebGrid(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    alternatingRowStyle:"webgrid-alternating-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.FirstLast | WebGridPagerModes.Numeric | WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious,
    numericLinksCount: 5,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Previous",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    nextText: "Next >",
    columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(columnName: "PersonId", header: "Person ID", style: "colId", format: (item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PersonId) ? string.Empty : item.PersonId),

             grid.Column(header: "Details", style: "colDetails", format: @<text><input class="colDetails1" id="btnDetails" type="button" value="Details" /></text>),
              ))
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var tr = $('#grid').find('tr');
    tr.bind('click', function (event) {

        $("tr").click(function () { $(this).css('background', 'yellow'); });

    });

});
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be welcome! :) Render some html and add this js code to it.

Comment: thanks but i am very new to jquery. not sure how to do this. my demo is today. :)

Comment: Go to the jsfiddle.net - paste some HTML code and JAVASCRIPT code, click Save and give us the link :)

Comment: Ok - forget the JSFiddle. Answered your question. ;) But be aware of such a great tool. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
var tr = $('#grid').find('tr');
tr.bind('click', function (event) {

    $("tr").click(function () { 
    $('#grid').find('tr').css('background', 'none');
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow'); });

});

});
```

Comment: wow almost worked, but only webgrid header background (blue) is gone because of background none. mmm

Comment: I don't know what background color was defined in the begining: thats another reason why i needed jsFiddle for. Change 'none' to the color the row has before clicking on it.

Comment: yay i managed it. i changed   $('#grid').find('tr').css('background', ' '); it is working. BINGO! thanks very much :) @Mr.TK

Comment: after clicking pagination of webgrid. Click event lost. any solution?

Comment: Page content is being changed - the elements you've defined events for are no longer on page. `$(document).on('click', '#grid tr', function(){ do something here });`
Work with that